# Gracefully handling 404 in Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm using `XmlHttpObject` to get a bunch of files from the server. Those files aren't crucial for my application so if any of them is missing I just want to log the error and continue anyway. Problem is, whenever a file is not found an exception is raised and that breaks all the code after.

```
function loadFile(path) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.status == 404) {
            // I can live with that, log it and go on
            console.log("file missing");
            return;
        }

        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            // Wohoo, all is fine, do loading stuff
        }
    }

    xhr.open("GET", path, true);
    xhr.send();
}

// Some time after
for (var i in files) {
    loadFile(file[i]);
    // If a file is not found, an exception is raised and the code below doesnt execute
}
// More stuff
```

What can I do to get that behaviour?

Comment: This seems odd. You are doing an asynchronous request so `loadFile` will return directly after calling `xhr.send()` and keep executing. Running `loadFile("http://www.example.com/test"); console.log("Foo");` will print "Foo" perfectly fine (and later the "file missing" part). Are you sure your exception is raised in `loadFile`?

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want to do is pass in a function that should be called when the file has been loaded. And as Tys pointed out you should probably check the readystate before checking the status:

```
function loadFile(path, onsuccess, onnotfound) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 404) {
                // Do error handling when request is complete
                onnotfound(xhr);
                return;
            }
            // Wohoo, all is fine, do loading stuff
            onsuccess(xhr);
        }
    }

    xhr.open("GET", path, true);
    xhr.send();
}

// Some time after
for (var i in files) {
    loadFile(file[i], function(xhr) {
        // Stuff to process a successfull response  
        // Adding things to the DOM etc etc. based on the response
    },
    function(xhr) { 
        console.log("file missing");
        // Additional error handling on file missing
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your blocks are wrongly ordered. Only check for the xhr.status when the xhr.readyState has changed to 4. You were checking for the status prematurely.

```
function loadFile(path) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 404) {
                // I can live with that, log it and go on
                console.log("file missing");
            }
            else {
                // Wohoo, all is fine, do loading stuff
            }
        }
    }

    xhr.open("GET", path, true);
    xhr.send();
}

// Some time after
for (var i in files) {
    loadFile(file[i]);
    // If a file is not found, an exception is raised and the code below doesnt execute
}
// More stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're programming in chrome the only way to fix it is by disabling this message in the console. According to the [Chromium team](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124534) it's a feature, not a bug. Go figure.  Check if you get the error in firefox, if not, then it's probably this.